# Correlation coefficient of two continuous random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, covariance, correlation

I have two continuous RVs $u$ and $v$ where
$$U=\frac{X}{Y+1};~V=\frac{Y}{X+1} $$
Here $X$ and $Y$ are exponential RVs: $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-y}$ which are independent. I want to find correlation coefficient between $u$ and $v$. By definition, $$cor(U,V)=\frac{cov(U,V)}{\sigma_u\sigma_v}.$$
However, again
$$cov(u,v)=\int\int F_{U,V}(u,v)-F_{U}(u)F_{V}(v)du dv$$
I am unable to compute this, specially because of the joint density. Can someone please help me?

---

With @Graham's guide, I calculate 
$$cov(u,v)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xy e^{-(x+y)}}{(1+x)(1+y)}dxdy -\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x e^{-(x+y)}}{(1+y)}dxdy \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y e^{-(x+y)}}{(1+x)}dxdy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\Cov{\mathop{\sf Cov}}\def\E{\mathop{\sf E}}\def\d{\mathop{\rm d}}$

No.  You have no need to find the joint density (or even the marginal) of $U,V$.

By definition (and totally not what you had): $$\Cov(U,V) = \E(UV)-\E(U)\E(V)$$

and by the Law of the Unconscious Statatician: $$ \E(g(X,Y)) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty g(x,y) e^{-x}e^{-y}\d x\d y$$

You have $U(x,y)=x/(1+y)$ and $V(x,y)= y/(1+x)$

---

PS: It may help to know the [Exponential Integral Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html), $\def\Ei{\mathop{\rm Ei}}\Ei(t)$ is defined as: $$\Ei(t) := \int_{-t}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s}~\d s$$

Comment: Can you please check what I tried with your guide? I have updated the problem. I can solve that integral with `Ei(.)` function.